# How to remove DocumentViewer drop-shadow?

Tags: c#, wpf, documentviewer, dropshadow

How can I remove the drop-shadow from the DocumentViewer control?
If I use `docViewer.ShowPageBorders = false` the normal border around the document is gone too. When I set a BorderBrush the border goes around the control and not the document.
Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[image]

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it by creating my own style which overrides the built in style (along with `ShowPageBorders="False"`):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DocumentPageView}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <!-- custom styles here -->
</Style>
```

By using a custom `Template` for your `DocumentmentViewer` you can change how it all looks even more.

Comment: Can you add some more context? I attempted to create a custom style as you suggested but could not get it to work.

Comment: Hello, please could you add the full style  code, i want to add my custom page template but i Failed.